# Google Tag Manager - Get alt text of nearby image

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I would like to capture the alt text of a nearby image when I click on a CTA

Here's my html structure

```html
<div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey">
    <img width="340" height="100" src="https://zero.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/a- solutions.jpg"       class="vc_single_image-img attachment-full" alt="A Solutions" decoding="async" loading="lazy"   title="A Solutions" srcset="https://zero.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/a-solutions.jpg 340w,   https://zero.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/a-solutions-300x88.jpg 300w" sizes="(max-width: 340px)   100vw, 340px" data-dt-location="https://zero.com/a-solutions/"></div>

<div id="modal-trg-txt-wrap-9188" class="ult-modal-input-wrapper ult-adjust-bottom-margin              vc_custom_1688547016180  " data-keypress-control="keypress-control-enable" data-overlay-control="overlay-control-enable"><span data-ultimate-target="#modal-trg-txt-wrap-9188 .mycust" data-responsive-json-new="{&quot;font-size&quot;:&quot;desktop:18px;&quot;,&quot;line-height&quot;:&quot;desktop:22px;&quot;}" style="color:#fe9015;cursor:pointer; " data-class-id="content-64ad22a65fe848-86090260" class="overlay-show team-modal-link  ult-responsive mycust ult-align-center" data-overlay-class="overlay-fade">More details</span></div>
```

While I can capture the CTA click of "More Details", I want to capture the alt text of the image with class vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey.

Here's the javascript variable I created.

```js
function() {   
  var e= {{Find Closest}}({{Click Element}},
   '.vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey');
   e= e.querySelector("p img");
   e= e.getAttribute("alt");
   return e;
}
```

I returned an undefined result.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: `'.vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey'` - this would select an element with the _tag name_ `vc_box_border_grey`, that is a descendant of an element with the class `vc_single_image-wrapper`. You are a) missing a dot here, to make that second one a _class_ selector, and b) the descendant combinator between the two of them needs to be removed - you want to select _one_ element based on that it has _both_ classes here, and not one element that is nested into another. `'.vc_single_image-wrapper.vc_box_border_grey'`